# Syncfusion nested grid behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, syncfusion

Hi I have a GridDataControl which is related to a child grid through a relation. There is a behavior applied on the parent grid which formats the grid and gets the column header names. I want to apply this same behavior to the child grid. The data for both grids is in the same format, however the main child grid is not accessible, only its columns are via the GridDataVisibleColumn property.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: So... why is the child grid not accessible? In what context? How is it related through a relation? Maybe it's just me, but I'm not sure what exactly you're asking here amigo...

Answer (score 0):

While using behaviour for Parent grid, you can get the child grid using RecordExpanded event of ParentGrid like the below code snippet.

Code Snippet:

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    this.AssociatedObject.Model.Table.RecordExpanded += Parent_RecordExpanded;
    base.OnAttached();
}

private void Parent_RecordExpanded(object sender, GridDataValueEventArgs<GridDataRecord> e)
{
    var mainGridColumns = e.Value.Table.Model.TableProperties.VisibleColumns;
    //Here header style is applied to first column in Parent grid.
    mainGridColumns[0].HeaderStyle = new GridDataColumnStyle();
    mainGridColumns[0].HeaderStyle.Background = Brushes.Red;
    var childGridColumns = e.Value.ChildModels[0].Table.Model.TableProperties.VisibleColumns;

    //Here, header style is applied to first column of nested grid.
    childGridColumns[0].HeaderStyle = new GridDataColumnStyle();
    childGridColumns[0].HeaderStyle.Background = Brushes.Brown;
    e.Value.ChildModels[0].Table.CurrentCellValidating += Table_CurrentCellValidating;
}

void Table_CurrentCellValidating(object sender, GridDataCurrentCellValidatingEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var item in (sender as GridDataTable).Model.TableProperties.VisibleColumns)
    {
        if (item.MappingName == "OrderID")
        {
            // do action
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the child grid from the ChildModels like the above code snippet. The ChildModels contains the number of nested grid in the parent grid.

Here I have changed the header style for first column in parent grid as well as nested grid and also I have used the CurrentCellValidating event of Nested grid. Likewise, you can use any events in nested grid and get the details.